# BCP text file with special characters (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm stuck at a very simple bcp and am hoping someone here could tell what i am doing wrong...
I have a single column textfile contaning email addresses. I'm trying to BCP this to SQL server using "bcp" command. Below is the sample file and the command I'm using.

I have used bcp before with different sets of files, but never had an issue. Any idea why this file wouldn't load?

```
D.out
'a@a.com'
'b@b.com'
'c@c.com'

bcp command: 
bcp temp_sf_email in D.out -SMyDBServer\INSTANCEA -T -w
```

Looks basic. But when run, doesnt do anything. The output I got is:
    Starting Copy.....
    0 Rows copied.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions..
Regards,
Simak

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest this sintax for `BCP command`

```
bcp db_name.schema_name.table in "drive:\folder\file.ext" -SServer -T -c
```

**example for your case**:

```
bcp yourdb.dbo.temp_sf_email in "c:\folder\D.out" -SMyDBServer\INSTANCEA -T -c
```

use the flag **-c** that means **-c character type** instead -w

[for more info about BCP click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162802.aspx)

*NOTE: I tested this example in SQL2005 and it work, btw you didnt specificy which SQL version was used*

Hope it help